# Use environment variable directly in CircleCI steps

Tags: circleci

Given the below step in a 2.0 CircleCI workflow:

```
- persist_to_workspace:
    root: .
    paths:
      - foo/bar
```

Is it possible to use an environment variable instead of `foo/bar`?

Comment: Support for env vars across the various keys in `config.yml` is uneven across the format. You could try it: either try an env var set up in the UI, or try an env var specified in a `environment` key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called environment variable interpolation, and it's not supported for workspace paths.